# Juntos para o bem da comunidade: quais os problemas que você enxerga na comunidade?

Tags: debate

Muito obrigado a [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) pela tradução.

---

É impossível aprender algo se você não sabe nada sobre aquilo: saber qual é o assunto e até que ponto ele está disponível é extremamente importante. O problema de criar, acumular e manter conhecimento sobre programação é o mesmo no mundo todo, mas possui algumas variações de acordo com o idioma, devido à diferenças na cultura e história de cada comunidade em particular. Por exemplo, ao olhar para o Stack Overflow em Inglês, vemos uma característica única - antes do site existir, haviam dois problemas críticos:

- Não existia uma base de conhecimento estruturada. Encontrar respostas para qualquer pergunta era muito difícil e tomava muito tempo.
- Os resultados de busca eram links para sites que não mostravam o seu conteúdo, a menos que se pagasse pelo acesso ao mesmo.

Todos sofriam, sem exceções. O ponto de virada na vida de comunidade falante de inglês aconteceu quando as pessoas se uniram para atacar esses problemas: eles lançaram o Stack Overflow e começaram a reunir conhecimento no site, sob a licença CC-BY-SA.

Acredito que o Stack Overflow em Português tem grande chance de se tornar uma das principais fontes de conhecimento em Português, similar ao que o Stack Overflow em Inglês se tornou na vida de desenvolvedores falantes de Inglês. Para atingir este sucesso, precisamos trabalhar juntos para resolver os principais problemas de toda a comunidade falante de Português. O primeiro passo é coletar os problemas que nós vemos. Depois, discutir e escolher aqueles que queremos resolver. Em seguida, solucionar estes problemas juntos, para o bem da comunidade.

"Uma grande jornada começa com um pequeno passo". Eu sugiro começarmos nossa jornada o quanto antes! Por favor compartilhe suas ideias sobre os problemas da comunidade que você ou seus colegas enxergam. Para que o processo de análise seja mais fácil, eu preparei várias perguntas para servir de guia. Por favor escreva sobre os problemas da comunidade na forma de respostas para estas perguntas.

**Atenção**: Nas perguntas abaixo, "comunidade" se refere a desenvolvedores de software falantes de Português em geral, não apenas usuários do Stack Overflow em Português.

1. Quais problemas você tem quando está procurando respostas na internet para perguntas sobre programação em Português? O que te causa mais frustração? Como você melhoraria isso?
2. Onde você procura respostas para perguntas sobre programação em Português? Qual o principal problema desses sites? Como você resolveria esses problemas?
3. No que você gasta mais tempo quando está procurando respostas? Como você poderia melhorar este processo?
4. Qual o problema mais comum que a maioria dos desenvolvedores falantes de Português encontra?
5. O que impede a comunidade de criar uma base de conhecimento gratuita em Português? Como você resolveria este problema?
6. Você faz perguntas de programação para seus colegas, de forma *offline* ? Como é esse processo? O que você faria para melhorá-lo?

Por favor, junte-se à discussão e convide seus colegas a participar! O todo é maior que a soma de suas partes.

---

Se você quiser responder as perguntas acima de forma anônima, por favor use o [Google Forms](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1DfounSTNwumeInkx1EvDTJcwv9fooRTZysXhr2cD_5w/viewform). Todas as respostas anônimas serão levadas em conta em discussões futuras.

Answer (score 13):

> What problems do you personally experience when looking for answers to your programming questions in the Portuguese language on the internet? What causes the most frustration? How would you improve this?

Não acredito que seja muito diferente do inglês e outras línguas, ainda que possa haver algo pontual de diferente. Eu poderia destacar o fato de latinos (de língua ou de região), em especial brasileiros costumam ser mais informais e muitas vezes desleixados que outras culturas (me desculpem se isto ofende alguém, não é minha intenção, mas é um fato conhecido, e claro, estou generalizando, nem todos são assim, eu sou, ainda que menos que  média). Por causa disto toda a qualidade geral fica mais baixa e achar algo útil se torna complicado porque cai naquela coisa da agulha no palheiro.

Na nossa língua poucas pessoas são preocupadas com a profundidade da discussão, com a precisão do que está fazendo e dizendo ou de fundamentação, então tudo vira um pouco receita de bolo.

Existe um outro problema mais geral nas buscas. Com a era da geração de conteúdo, quem sabe "divulgar" melhor se sobressai sobre o conteúdo melhor. Algumas coisas atrapalham até de forma orgânica. A informação rasa acaba aparecendo mais que a de nicho, detalhada e avançada. Isso acho que nem a Google sabe como resolver.

Pra mim o maior problema de outros lugares é ter zero formas de classificação minimamente confiáveis. Aqui temos alguma, mas é falha. Quem não tem capacidade de qualificar algo tem poder demais para isto e quem tem capacidade acaba tendo o mesmo poder, e proporcionalmente pela quantidade de pessoas qualificadas em relação às menos qualificadas acaba tendo menos poder. O SO considera que a pessoa fazer um *post* minimamente aceito em um assunto dá o direito da pessoa qualificar qualquer coisa no site.

> Where do you find answers on programming questions [in the Portuguese language] today? What do you see as the main problem on these sites? How would you solve them?

O grosso é no SO, especialmente em inglês, em segundo é no SOpt mesmo, e fora isto em lugares muito variados, geralmente blogs de alguns especialistas, o que é raro ter com qualidade. O maior problema é não saber de antemão se tem qualidade e quase sempre não tem muita. A impressão que dá é que no mínimo é mais difícil achar coisas em português, mesmo tendo menos conteúdo, quase tudo parece um pouco com ruído. Não tenho solução, lido como fato da vida e uso do meu senso.

Também acho muito em documentação, mas em inglês, a documentação em português é muito ruim, eu mesmo estou começando me esforçar pra melhorar isso, mas é enxugar gelo.

Isto ocorre aqui também, temos hoje mais ruído que música e a música fica sufocada.

> On what do you spend the most time when looking for an answer? How would you improve this process?

Google, não tem nada que eu possa fazer. A busca do SO é uma das piores coisas que eu já vi e serve pouco pra achar alguma coisa, normalmente só uso para achar algo meu para *linkar* em outra resposta que já sei bem como achar fácil.

Aqui teria que pensar em maneiras de dar mais visibilidade a conteúdo de qualidade. Precisaria mudar muita coisa, mas eu até já perdi a vontade de discutir isso mais a fundo porque todas as vezes acabou ficando a mesma coisa. Há um tendência da empresa Stack Overflow de privilegiar a quantidade, mesmo que o discurso não seja esse. Agora ele tem que fazer pra conquistar credibilidade sobre o discurso da qualidade.

> What is the common problem that most Portuguese-speaking developers experience?

Acho que é a falta de educação geral. Há falta de entendimento mínimo de comunicação de matemática básica, de ciência no seu mínimo (sem nada específico), do que é de fato importante para sua profissão.

Vejo um outro problema recente que muitas pessoas com dúvidas de programação não são desenvolvedores, são pessoas que precisam de alguma ferramenta de programação para executar seu trabalho. Pra mim isto é outro tipo de público e causa ruído em um site de desenvolvedores. A solução para isto é complicada e causa outro problema.

> What prevents the community from creating a free knowledge base in the Portuguese language? How would you solve this problem?

Não posso responder isso com propriedade, mas eu considero dois pontos:

- a falta de vontade de fazer algo de qualidade. Vale para quem pergunta e para quem responde. As pessoas não querem gastar muito tempo com isso mesmo que na prática acabe gastando mais sem perceber quando considera o longo prazo
- muitas pessoas não estão qualificadas para escrever aquilo, mas faz mesmo assim e nem sabe que não tem essa qualificação, outras vezes sabem mas a gamificação faz ela agir assim.

Mas pra mim o pior é a duplicidade de esforços, de informação. É completamente utópico, mas uma informação deveria ser sempre canônica, de preferência na internet toda, pelo menos naquela língua. Em um local deveria ter tudo o que precisa e ser fácil localizar, e ter todas vertentes sobre aquilo. A Wikipedia deveria ser isso, mas está longe de ser.

> Do you ask colleagues programming questions “offline”? What does this process look like? How would you improve this process?

Sim, claro, em conversas diretas pessoalmente ou por mensageiro eletrônico.

Na verdade acho as perguntas um pouco abertas demais para servir como algo que possa ser mais que dar uma ideia geral da situação. E um dos motivos de eu não ter um motivação tão forte em dar respostas melhores. Até o fato de não ser sobre o SOpt de forma muito específica ajuda um pouco nessa sensação.

O resumo é que no SO é um pouco mais organizado, um pouco melhor pra classificar qualidade, mas ainda tem muitos defeitos, alguns que dão pra resolver outros são difíceis ou impossíveis.

O que mais vejo de problema é falta de qualidade das pessoas que estão no site, começando por mim, passando por vários outros, principalmente porque alguns que estavam acima da média saíram, mas termina com todos os outros, especialmente os que não fazem parte do que podemos chamar de comunidade de verdade (quem só aparece para postar alguma coisa em isolado não é comunidade).

E as pessoas estão cansando de enxugar gelo. Pra melhorar tem que ficar monitorando demais, tem que agir demais, tem que fazer zeladoria demais, mesmo fazendo tanto ainda o ruído se sobressai.

Answer (score 4):

> Quais problemas você tem quando está procurando respostas na internet para perguntas sobre programação em Português? O que te causa mais frustração? Como você melhoraria isso?

Sobre este quesito, o que mais me frustra é geralmente a **falta de documentação** em português. Não que seja um problema para mim, eu sou falante de inglês. Mas para muitas pessoas é difícil ter que traduzir ou ter que aprender toda uma nova língua apenas para aprender a estudar programação.
Não é difícil achar no site links de "fontes" ou leituras adicionais para sites em inglês e isso para iniciantes é, às vezes, um pesadelo. Ainda mais por que existem muitos termos intraduzíveis que acabam sendo traduzidos pelos Googles Translators pelo mundo.

Não acredito que haja muito o que o StackOverflow faça por isso, uma vez que não se pode criar um guia de "passo a passo" para se iniciar na programação.  Mas estimular e criar tags *user-friendly* talvez ajudariam muitas pessoas a se situarem no site. Além disso, posso recomendar analisar quais são os termos de pesquisa que mais levam ao site e quais as linguagens que mais recebem acesso e estimular a publicação de perguntas daquelas linguagens que sejam interessantes. Até mesmo perguntas que geralmente as pessoas não tem dúvida mas que são muito interessantes de se saber, um bom exemplo seria esta pergunta: [Como implementações alternativas de linguagens funcionam, como Python na JVM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/384174/como-implementa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-alternativas-de-linguagens-funcionam-como-python-na-jvm).