# Quais são as métricas que a SE utiliza para medir progresso de um site?

Tags: debate

Na pergunta [Vamos medir os esforços da comunidade usando métricas específicas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7825/5878) é questionado sobre quais são as métricas que a comunidade gostaria de ter para medir o progresso geral do site.

Aliado a isso, eu gostaria de saber:

1. Quais são as métricas que a própria SE utiliza para analisar o progresso de um site na rede, em especial os sites internacionais?
2. Como são levantados esses dados?
3. Com qual periodicidade é feito a análise?
4. Quem faz a análise?
5. E, principalmente, o que fazem após a análise?

Os resultados levantados a partir desses relatórios ficam acessíveis à comunidade? Se sim, como?

[English version](https://gist.github.com/acwoss/b70eb06c1b9478aee52cc85e56e73312)

Answer (score 5):

Muito obrigado a [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) pela tradução.

---

#### Não há um processo oficial para avaliar um site depois que este é graduado

Nós não medimos ativamente o progresso dos sites da rede Stack Exchange depois que eles entram em beta público. A viabilidade é avaliada na fase de proposta da Área 51, e também durante o beta privado, mas desde que os [requisitos mínimos para manter um site aberto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/274323) foram adotados, nunca houve uma indicação clara sobre o que a empresa quer que esses sites façam. Nós apenas abrimos os sites para as comunidades e não avaliamos ativamente o progresso de nenhum deles. Temos algumas métricas objetivas para determinar quando os sites deveriam ter certas características (por exemplo, ser graduado quando atinge X perguntas por dia), mas nada além disso.

Ao mesmo tempo, olhamos as estatísticas de um site sob demanda. Por exemplo:

- Há uma ferramenta que cria uma amostra aleatória de postagens, para verificar a qualidade do conteúdo do site.
- No Stack Overflow em Russo nós comemoramos [alguns marcos](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b8) como ["tantas mil perguntas"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8572/6) ou ["chegamos a X perguntas por dia"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7399/6).
- Para entender como o site está se saindo, olhamos para perguntas por dia, porcentagem de perguntas respondidas e métricas relacionadas a quantidade de respostas por pergunta.

Há muitos outros casos em que olhamos para os dados, quando há a necessidade para tal.

### Por que? A história da rede Stack Exchange

Aviso: a história a seguir é sob o meu ponto de vista, eu me juntei à empresa muitos anos depois dos eventos abaixo. Ao mesmo tempo espero que esta história deixe mais claros alguns pontos.

#### Stack Overflow em Inglês

O Stack Overflow em Inglês foi lançado com um [objetivo claro](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/):

> É feito por programadores, para programadores, com o objetivo final de aumentar coletivamente a soma de todo conhecimento bom sobre programação no mundo.

É muito importante mencionar que, na época em que o site foi lançado:

- Era necessário entrar em debates intermináveis em fóruns, listas de discussão e manuais, a fim de encontrar uma pista sobre como resolver um problema.
- Experts-Exchange aparecia nos resultados de busca na maior parte do tempo. Se você não ouviu falar no Experts-Exchange, é um site no qual você precisava pagar para ter acesso às respostas. Na época o site tinha todo o conteúdo indexado pelo Google, mas quando uma pessoa chegava no site através de uma busca, o conteúdo ficava borrado e pedia que a pessoa pagasse por ele.

Como resultado, por trás da missão do Stack Overflow havia uma grande necessidade de uma fonte de informação sobre programação que fosse grátis e estruturada.

Como resultado, de forma bem aproximada, havia duas métricas para o Stack Overflow:

- *Interna*: O quão bem a *engine* resolve o problema de estruturar e manter o conhecimento? Em outras palavras, qual a razão entre o sinal e o ruído no site?
- *Externa*: Com que frequência o Stack Overflow aparece nos resultados de busca em vez do Experts-Exchange ...ou em nenhum dos resultados? Em outras palavras, qual a cobertura da base de conhecimento da comunidade?

#### A trilogia, Área 51 e a rede Stack Exchange

O Stack Overflow em Inglês era (é, e espero que continue sendo) uma comunidade próspera. Ela estava crescendo rápido, com novos tópicos surgindo. A comunidade decidiu separar as perguntas de programação de outras menos técnicas e mais voltadas à administração de sistemas. Surgiu então [A Trilogia](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/31/the-stack-overflow-trilogy). Para que o "processo de divisão celular" ocorresse de forma suave, [foi criado um site especial, a Área 51](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/16/area-51-we-come-in-peace). Neste site as pessoas começaram a sugerir não apenas um outro pedaço do Stack Overflow para uma comunidade específica, mas também tópicos completamente novos e não-técnicos, como [culinária](https://cooking.stackexchange.com) e [fotografia](https://photo.stackexchange.com). Nascia a rede Stack Exchange.

#### O que isso significa?

Eu acho que a forma como o Stack Overflow em Inglês surgiu é bem diferente dos outros sites da rede. O Stack Overflow em Inglês foi a solução para um problema que existia na época - a falta de uma base de conhecimento de programação grátis e bem estruturada. É por isso que este é o único site que tinha (e tem) tanto métricas internas quanto externas, mesmo depois do lançamento público.

### Stack Overflow em Português

Imagine um mundo onde uma pessoa falante de português, de qualquer idade ou classe social, tem acesso ilimitado a conhecimentos sobre programação. Um mundo onde qualquer desenvolvedor que fale portugês, sem exceções, possa contar com a ajuda de seus pares. Um mundo onde pessoas com diferentes qualificações, especializações e experiências possam complementar umas às outras. Este é o mundo que estamos construindo para nós e nossos colegas. Temos em nossas mãos [uma grande ferramenta para organizar o conhecimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com), uma [grande missão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto) e [ótimas regras da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com). A pergunta é *Qual o problema que os desenvolvedores que falam português querem resolver coletivamente com o Stack Overflow em Português?* - apenas quando definirmos o problema a ser resolvido, teremos a resposta para cada item da sua pergunta.

A propósito, quais problemas você vê? Quais deles você gostaria de resolver? O que você acha?

---

Perguntas relacionadas:

- [Juntos para o bem da comunidade: quais os problemas que você enxerga na comunidade?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7790/17539)
- [O que acha sobre sites com conteúdos traduzidos automaticamente para Português do Stack Overflow em Inglês?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7550/17539)